# Mutate error with python and mutate? Error in mutate(), caused by error: "SystemError: <class 'super'> returned a result with an error set"

Tags: r, tidyverse, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis, reticulate

I'm trying to implement a sentiment analysis using reticulate and huggingfaceR in my database, this code already worked previously, but now that I try to implement it to create a new variable it returns the following error:

```
"Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `distilBERT_sent = distilBERT(textOriginal)`.
Caused by error:
! SystemError: <class 'super'> returned a result with an error set"
```

My code follows:

```
#Packages ----
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
install_miniconda()
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("farach/huggingfaceR")
library(huggingfaceR)
#modelo ----
hf_python_depends("transformers")

distilBERT <- hf_load_pipeline(
  model_id = "distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english", 
  task = "text-classification"
)

#sentiment analysis and load table ----
unsc_com <- read_csv("unsc_com_new.csv")
View(unsc_com)

teste <- unsc_com %>%
  filter(text_length < 512 & country_presidency == "Brazil") %>%
  mutate(distilBERT_sent = distilBERT(textOriginal),
         .before = textDisplay) %>%
  unnest_wider(distilBERT_sent)
```

When I use rlang::last_trace() it shows:

```
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `distilBERT_sent = distilBERT(textOriginal)`.
Caused by error:
! SystemError: <class 'super'> returned a result with an error set
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% unnest_wider(distilBERT_sent)
  2. ├─tidyr::unnest_wider(., distilBERT_sent)
  3. │ └─tidyr:::check_data_frame(data)
  4. │   └─base::is.data.frame(x)
  5. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  6. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., distilBERT_sent = distilBERT(textOriginal), .before = textDisplay)
  7. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
  8. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  9. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 10. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 11. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
 12. ├─reticulate (local) distilBERT(textOriginal)
 13. │ └─reticulate:::py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
 14. └─base::stop(`<Rcpp::xc>`)
```

and

```
rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE)
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `distilBERT_sent = distilBERT(textOriginal)`.
Caused by error:
! SystemError: <class 'super'> returned a result with an error set
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% unnest_wider(distilBERT_sent)
  2. ├─tidyr::unnest_wider(., distilBERT_sent)
  3. │ └─tidyr:::check_data_frame(data)
  4. │   └─base::is.data.frame(x)
  5. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  6. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., distilBERT_sent = distilBERT(textOriginal), .before = textDisplay)
  7. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
  8. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  9. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 10. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 11. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
 12. ├─reticulate (local) distilBERT(textOriginal)
 13. │ └─reticulate:::py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
 14. ├─base::stop(`<Rcpp::xc>`)
 15. └─dplyr (local) `<fn>`(`<Rcpp::xc>`)
 16.   └─rlang::abort(message, class = error_class, parent = parent, call = error_call)
```

I have already reinstalled the packages but I did not work and I could not get any better insight from this problem.